# Change TextView twice

Tags: android, multithreading, settext

i want to create a similar "bar progress" but with text. I think do this, but not work.

```
 public void changeTextTwice(View v) throws InterruptedException {

    miEdad.setText("example 1");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    miEdad.setText("example 2");

 }
```

Just show the last setText. How can i do it?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.os.Handler for performing a job with a delay.

```
public void changeTextTwice(View v){

    miEdad.setText("example 1");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    miEdad.setText("example 2");
                }
            });

        }
   },2000);
}
```

Otherwise if you want to do something download etc you can use the AsyncTask like this

```
   private class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            miEdad.setText("example 1");
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do your job here

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            miEdad.setText("example 2");
        }
    }
```

and call it on your method like this

`new DownloadAsync().execute();`

Note that if you want to call UI methods like `setText()` etc on the `doInBackground()` you have to use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable)` like this

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call ui methods here 
            }
        });
```

Comment: My other comment, below. I have a method and try to call inside run() but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is called so fast, that your eyes will never see the first setText. You will only see the last one.

There are different solutions depending on what progress you want to show. If you want to show the progress of a file being downloaded, then look into AsyncTask. There are several great tutorials: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/